# How do I understand the public static Objective[]?

Tags: java

```
  public class Objective {
private int problemNumber;          // The problem number from the original board game
private String initialState;        // The list of initial tile placements
public static Objective[] OBJECTIVES = {
        // STARTER
        new Objective("S0S6W3N8N2E5S7S18", 1),
        new Objective("N7N0S3N8S2S6E1S51", 2),
        new Objective("W8S6E2S5N0E4W1S31", 3),
        new Objective("S8S7W0E5S4N2W3S13", 4),
        new Objective("S1N2W0E7S6S8W3W58", 5),
        new Objective("W8N6E7S4N0W1N2S32", 6),
        new Objective("S2N0W1E8S7W4W6W38", 7),
        new Objective("S6N8W5E4W7W1S3N23", 8),
        new Objective("S3S7W6S4W1E5N2S05", 9),
        new Objective("S0S1N2N7S6W3N4S57", 10),
        new Objective("E2N8W7N1S6E4S3S06", 11),
        new Objective("N1S3W0W7N5E8E6S28", 12),
        ", 53),
       


public static Objective newObjective(int difficulty) {
    assert difficulty >= 0 && difficulty <= 4;
    return OBJECTIVES[0]; // FIXME Task 5 (P)
}

public String getInitialState() {
    return initialState;
}
public int getProblemNumber() {
    return problemNumber;
}

public static Objective getObjective(int index) {
    return OBJECTIVES[index];
}
public static Objective[] getOBJECTIVES() {
    return OBJECTIVES;
}
```

I just learn Java for two weeks, I still have some questions about this code.

```
public static Objective[] OBJECTIVES =
```

I don't understand this code. Is a method of the class?
public static Objective newObjective(int difficulty)
I also have no idea about this code.

Comment: Answering this question will require answering a lot of small individual questions (which is unfortunately not how stackoverflow goes about answering questions.)  I would recommend researching the "static" keyword and "java get and set property conventions" on google or stackoverflow.

Comment: p.s.  Whoever made that `static Objective[] OBJECTIVES` line needs to learn about get and set conventions, and class public api conventions also ;)

Comment: The code  `public static Objective[] OBJECTIVES = {` is starting off to be a declaration and initialization of an array, which continues normally until rudely interrupted by a **syntax error** at `", 53),`.  No wonder you're confused! (;-.)

Answer (score 1):

> public static Objective[] OBJECTIVES = { ...

This is an array of Objective objects that has been instantiated. The visibility of this array is public and the array is static so it is only created once for the Class. One thing to note is that `Objective` is not immutable and so this `shouldn't` be defined with all uppercase letters because it is inherently mutable.

> public static Objective newObjective(int difficulty)

The code suggests that a new Objective object should be returned based on the difficulty provided. I presume that refers to an index in the underlying array.

This question definitely needs more focus though. In the future ask a single question with a single point of focus and be clear when asking if possible.